# when integrity is implemented using encryption arises any problem?

Tags: encryption

when confidentiality is implemented using encryption arises a problem: "how the receiver knows the message is really sent by the sent as it is claims?".

when authentication  is implemented using encryption arises a problem: "is that anyone else, except the receiver can release the message contents ".

my question is: if when integrity is implemented using encryption arises any problem?

Answer (score 2):

There are problems with integrity when integrity is implemented with a system which *does not do the job*. This often arises when someone thought that *encryption* could ensure integrity (it does not).

Basically, that some data is *encrypted* does not prevent anyone from modifying it. The details of the encryption system may impact the degree of precision that the attacker can have in his modifications, but no commonly used encryption algorithm ensures that any modification results in utterly garbled data when decrypted (that's a widespread mental picture, but it is unfortunately a myth).

In most practical situations, where encryption is required, integrity should also be ensured. In other words, when there can be an attacker who can *spy* on the data, the same attacker can often *alter* the data, and possibly gain some knowledge on the data by altering it and see how honest systems react to the altered data. Thus, on a general basis, encryption should be combined with a [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Authentication_Code). Doing this combination properly is [not as easy as it seems](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac). There are [nifty encryption systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) which combine encryption and integrity, and do it well.

Answer (score 0):

Encryption alone provides only confidentiality, and not integrity and authenticity.

For a symmetric encryption like AES, you can use the authenticated encryption modes like EAX which makes use of a MAC (which provides integrity and authenticity). The idea is to encrypt a message and compute a MAC so that the receiver is able to compute the MAC and verify that he has received the correct intended message. The MAC is usually computed by a hash function with an input key and the message. Since it is assumed that an eavesdropper does not know the key, he should not be able to compute a valid MAC.

Or for an asymmetric encryption like RSA, you can make use digital signatures (which also provides integrity and authenticity). Now, with two different keys - public and private key, you encrypt the message with the public key of your receiver and then encrypt the "already encrypted message" with your private key to form a digital signature. The receiver simply uses your public key to decrypt the signature and check if it matches the encrypted message he received. Again, since an eavesdropper does not know your private key, he is unable to forge a valid signature.

Either way, you may need to share a separate key (other than your encryption key) for providing integrity checks. It is generally not advisable to use your encryption key as your MAC key.

So to answer your question: Yes, the encrypted message can be easily modified without detection.

As a simple example, lets use the bit-flipping attack on a stream cipher. Stream cipher like RC4 works by generating a pseudorandom binary sequence, C from the encryption key. Next the input message, m is XOR-ed with the pseudo-random sequence C to form the ciphertext. Therefore, lets say the whole encryption operation is

"Let's meet on Mon" XOR C.

Then it is possible for an attacker to modify "Mon" to "Tue" by XOR-ing the specific part of the cipher text by ("Mon" XOR "Tue"). The receiver can successfully decrypt the message "Let's meet on Tue" without any errors and is unable to detect the modification. Of course, I think such attacks are much harder on other encryption algorithms like AES or RSA but not impossible.